# Retaining the state (collapsed/expanded nodes) of a NestedTree when using BookmarkablePageLink

Tags: java, tree, wicket

I have a problem that I can't find an elegant solution for. I want to use a `NestedTree` (or something similar) as a simple menu for my page. Each node links to a `Page` that shows content that is identified by an ID. To get nice URLs and easy bookmarking I'd like to use `BookmarkablePageLinks` to link to these pages.

But doing it that way creates a completely new `Page` each time, thus destroying and recreating the tree, resetting it's state. So with each link click the complete tree collapses and the user has to open it again to choose another link.
I can't find a solution, that satisfies these criteria:

- Each tab/window retains a separate state
- Opening a new tab copies the state from the tab it's opened from, but is then independent
- Easy to use, meaning you don't have to manually set and restore state for each link

It would be okay if the state is not restored when the bookmarked URL is called.

With Wicket 1.4 I was able to use the `pageMapName` to maintain a map of `PageMaps` and their menu states in the session. But that functionality got altered substantially with Wicket 1.5 (I'm using 6.8 now).

I would be quite grateful for solutions or tips on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> But doing it that way creates a completely new Page each time, thus
>   destroying and recreating the tree, resetting it's state. So with each
>   link click the complete tree collapses and the user has to open it
>   again to choose another link.

The tree collapses because its model is being recreated on page load. You are probably keeping the tree's model as a member variable on the page. To get around this issue you should store the tree's model in the session object instead. This way you can retain the state across multiple pages.

Comment: That's what I was doing initially. Then I switched to storing the state in the session. But that means trouble when I have two tabs open: the state of the trees gets mixed/overwritten. Do you have a suggestion to keep track of several pages' tree state?

Comment: In that case I would proceed with svenmeier's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your own pageMaps in Wicket 1.5.x and 6.x. All you need is a little Javascript, see AjaxNewWindowNotifyingBehavior for inspiration.

Then you can keep the expansion state of your tree in your session under pageMap-specific keys.